# Wireshark Student - I can't see any http post or get requests

Tags: http, post, get, wireshark

I am a student and today for a lab, we were asked to install and use Wireshark. The installation went well, I installed the correct version, installed WinPcap, and the program started without any issues.

I was connected to the University's Wifi and as part of our lab we had to visit http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~rzheng/course/CAS4C03W17/Labs/INTRO-wireshark-file1.html and answer questions about the data captured in Wireshark.
Problem is, I am not getting any get or post requests, filtering by http.request.method == "GET" shows nothing, and http.request.method == "POST" shows nothing as well. Filtering by http shows the 200 OK and 304 Not Modified (if I refresh).

I was the only one in my lab who had this problem, and my instructor wasn't able to figure it out. He saved and sent me his output which has Get and Post requests so I can continue my work.

Did anyone have this problem before or have any idea on how to solve it? I can upload the saved outputs if you think it would help. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to see not filtered capture.

Comment: nnovich-OK here is the output, the 200 OK was not captured but the 304 was: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3SGwmI7i-wyMUZMNjJfQXd1YUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Capture sample looks like it's filtered, since it contains only packets sent to your PC IP address. What is missing:

- There is not a single outgoing packet, despite they are obviously on the net. E.g. there are "TCP acknowledge" packets received by PC in capture file, but packets sent by PC, which are acknowledged by them, aren't shown.
- Not a single incoming broadcast/multicast packet. This situation is possible, but not very likely.

So there is some trouble with sniffer setup on your site. Possible explanations:

1. accidentally configured [capture filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) (don't mix with [display filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters))
2. Some [interfering software](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/InterferingSoftware) is installed. Example of the same [complaint](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/27296/wireshark-only-capturing-incoming-packets)

Method to determine if issue is gone: apply `!(ip.dst == YOUR_IP_ADDR)` display filter and check if packets output isn't empty on visiting any web page. Possible plan of troubleshooting:

1. check capture filter
2. check different network card (e.g. non-wireless connection)
3. check wireshark operability in pure environment (e.g. liveUSB)
4. try removing suspected interfering software